# Regex pattern to extract Hearst patterns

Tags: regex

I am new to Regex and I am unable to extract hyponym-hypernym pairs in the form of  a list or tuple.
I tried using this pattern but I get no matches

```
(NP_[\w.]*(, NP_[\w.]*)*,? (and)? other NP_[\w.]*)
```

I have the following annotated sentences for 'and other' pattern:

1. NP_kimmel  faces  **NP_dui ,  NP_fleeing  or  NP_evading_police ,  and  other  NP_possible_charges** .
2. The  NP_network  has  asked  NP_big_bang_theory_co-creator_bill  prady  to  mastermind  the  NP_revival ,  which  would  see  the  NP_return  of  **NP_kermit  the  NP_frog ,  NP_miss_piggy ,  NP_fozzie_bear  and  other  NP_old_favorites** .

I want to extract a list such as :

```
[NP_dui,NP_fleeing or NP_evading_police, NP_possible_charges]
```

OR

```
(NP_dui,NP_possible_charges)
(NP_fleeing or NP_evading_police,NP_possible_charges)
```

Similarly for the sentence 2:

```
[NP_kermit the NP_frog , NP_miss_piggy , NP_fozzie_bear, NP_old_favorites]
```

or Similar tuples.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: this `NP_[\w.]*(?: the )?((\s,\s?| and other )*NP_[\w.]*( or NP_[\w.]*)?)+` is close except it isn't very clean and I am unfamiliar with your language [regex101](https://regex101.com/r/RWRit4/1)

Comment: I am using python. ` NP_[\w.]*` does extract every word starting with NP_ .

Comment: You have tagged this spaCy but it has nothing to do with spaCy as asked. If you actually use spaCy you can do this without fiddling with regexes. https://spacy.io/usage/rule-based-matching

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use

```py
NP_[\w.]*(?:\s*(?:,|\bor\b|,?\s*and(?:\s+other)?\b)\s*NP_[\w.]*)+
```

This extracts strings with your matches. Next, extract expected ents with `NP_[\w.]*`.

**[Python code](https://tio.run/##VVHNboMwDL7zFFYvLSvjsstUaeobTDvsVqoogIGIgCMnbdeq79459GcdBxR/f7EddwwdjW/vji8XMzjiAIxJEtAH5QN7@IDN7PNL9WYY0EKjK/Qgdb0zkMVDYxHN2AJxrHCva6mUI2sqFIUea6DQ4cQ68t6UFlXVaW7R57MsmX13GLkRw4G4h0570L7HOoKlaVWpJU8SiI@qoteKUQdioawFx7o@QiAYtA/Ig5HbwjWPcW/22koLh85UHRxoZ2vwiH@CsOMRqIlFH83hTjVM7XW6wXivnGnb421aOp0MqhI1/x@NbK0avSc2sjrIZ9vEyep4LtSmOOTbl8V6Vfj4z85FSVyU52wtgIRMzHJKStdFmQr6cKXLeZI0stv7g4AZH2e/SkC@QYeqw@mlthMQ9RMYxYx5I2vR1i5c9rCmV@uTPcefgNLMk/6p@6KcZ1dlmk5Ox2YMi5s3vVx@AQ)**:

```py
import re

test_strs = ["NP_kimmel faces NP_dui , NP_fleeing or NP_evading_police , and other NP_possible_charges.",
"The NP_network has asked NP_big_bang_theory_co-creator_bill prady to mastermind the NP_revival , which would see the NP_return of NP_kermit the NP_frog , NP_miss_piggy , NP_fozzie_bear and other NP_old_favorites ."]
p = r'NP_[\w.]*(?:\s*(?:,|\bor\b|,?\s*and(?:\s+other)?\b)\s*NP_[\w.]*)+'

for test_str in test_strs:
    matches = []
    for match in re.findall(p, test_str):
        matches.extend(re.findall(r'NP_[\w.]*\b', match))
    print(matches)
```

**Results**:
`['NP_dui', 'NP_fleeing', 'NP_evading_police', 'NP_possible_charges']`
`['NP_frog', 'NP_miss_piggy', 'NP_fozzie_bear', 'NP_old_favorites']`

**EXPLANATION**

```py
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  NP_                      'NP_'
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  [\w.]*                   any character of: word characters (a-z, A-
                           Z, 0-9, _), '.' (0 or more times (matching
                           the most amount possible))
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  (?:                      group, but do not capture (1 or more times
                           (matching the most amount possible)):
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    \s*                      whitespace (\n, \r, \t, \f, and " ") (0
                             or more times (matching the most amount
                             possible))
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    (?:                      group, but do not capture:
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
      ,                        ','
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
     |                        OR
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
      \b                       the boundary between a word char (\w)
                               and something that is not a word char
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
      or                       'or'
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
      \b                       the boundary between a word char (\w)
                               and something that is not a word char
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
     |                        OR
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
      ,?                       ',' (optional (matching the most
                               amount possible))
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
      \s*                      whitespace (\n, \r, \t, \f, and " ")
                               (0 or more times (matching the most
                               amount possible))
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
      and                      'and'
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
      (?:                      group, but do not capture (optional
                               (matching the most amount possible)):
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
        \s+                      whitespace (\n, \r, \t, \f, and " ")
                                 (1 or more times (matching the most
                                 amount possible))
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
        other                    'other'
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
      )?                       end of grouping
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
      \b                       the boundary between a word char (\w)
                               and something that is not a word char
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    )                        end of grouping
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    \s*                      whitespace (\n, \r, \t, \f, and " ") (0
                             or more times (matching the most amount
                             possible))
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    NP_                      'NP_'
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    [\w.]*                   any character of: word characters (a-z,
                             A-Z, 0-9, _), '.' (0 or more times
                             (matching the most amount possible))
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  )+                       end of grouping
```

Comment: I tried this regex but it also extracts some other patterns, for example for a text:
**eliot spitzer will preview his first executive budget in a speech on friday afternoon , laying out his plan to rein in medicaid and other health care spending , setting the stage for a battle with politically powerful health care providers and unions .**

I get : **['friday afternoon', 'laying'] , ['medicaid', 'health care spending', 'setting']  and ['powerful health care providers', 'unions']** from the same sentence.

Comment: The annotated sentence is **NP_eliot_spitzer  will  preview  his  NP_first_executive_budget  in  a  NP_speech  on  NP_friday_afternoon ,  NP_laying  out  his  NP_plan  to  rein  in  NP_medicaid  and  other  NP_health_care_spending ,  NP_setting  the  NP_stage  for  a  NP_battle  with  politically  NP_powerful_health_care_providers  and  NP_unions .**

I tried to incorporate the "JJs" and "VBGs" as the modifiers of NPs in the annotated sentences